# How to make a tight layout with a logy pypplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I can't seem to auto-format my pyplot, even using `tight_layout()`. It seems that the longer ytick labels generated by the logplot confuse it. Minimum working example:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

f, a = plt.subplots()
f.tight_layout()

vals = [180 + i for i in range(100)]
a.semilogy(vals, basey=10)

f.savefig("result.png", format='png')
```

The result has partially obscured tick labels "x 10^2"

[image: Result of the example code]

Comment: Don't call tight_layout until the end.  Also, you could use constrained_layout instead as it tends to be more flexible.

Comment: @JodyKlymak thanks, that seems to have helped :-)